# Java class not found exception when used

Tags: java, class, jsoup

I am writing a web crawler using Jsoup, but I get a class not found exception when running the code after the class was properly imported. When I compiled a program that just imports the JSoup class without using it, it imports fine, but when I try to use the class I get an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at crawler.getLinksFromPage(crawler.java:14)
        at crawler.main(crawler.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

I imported all of the classes that get used and set the classpath to the jar file when I compiled it and it compiled without errors, but I keep getting thas exception when I run it.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
```

Comment: There's some issue with the classpath; it's not finding your jar. How are you running your program?

Comment: You have to use the same classpath at runtime that you used to compile.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use maven to build your project in order to avoid this kind of problems, here you can find the jsoup dependency that you need http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp .;youJsoup.jar com.your.main.faile.ClassName
```

Bottom line, before make sure you make use of the -classpath command line option to put in your system class loader search path any jar file that you depend upon.